# Cloud explorer value cannot be null, parameter name: user id

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to access my sql database by opening it from cloud explorer to sql server object explorer in visual studio 2015.

I get the following error:

```
 Cloud Explorer has encountered an unexpected error:

    The requested action could not be completed.
    Details: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: User ID
```

P.S. When I try to access it from my desktop, it works fine. The error occurs on my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same issue, when I tried adding a db to previously created instance of Azure Sql Server, which was already associated with another db.

Somehow VS SQLSOE wanted to have added a "second instance" of the same Sql Server in order to display the newly added db.

Solution:

- Disconnect the Azure SQL Server instance from SQL SOE window (right click this server, then Disconnect). If more than one appears disconnect them all.
- If the DB properly shows in the Cloud explorer, right click this DB and click "Open SQL Server Object Explorer" (if it does not show in Cloud Explorer this might be a different issue then)

Comment: A combination of both your and @Pantelis  answer worked for me. I had to disconnect all server and database instances in VS SQLSOE. And then I added the server and then the database from the "Add SQL server" button in the SQLSOE (I couldn't add them from Cloud Explorer, although I could see them and click open in SQLSOE).

Answer (score 7):

I've also experienced this problem with Azure Sql Databases, my guess is it has something to do with multiple accounts in VS 2015. It's the only thing changed recently, I added a 2nd account.

As a workaround I use the "Add SQL server" button directly in SQL Server Object Explorer, which in VS 2015 adds a firewall rule if needed.

Still, interested if someone has any other input on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This affects single/multiple accounts. 
The underlying issue may have something to do with Cloud Explorer for Visual Studio 2015 tooling.

Solution:

- Under SQL Server Object Explorer
- Add SQL Server
- Enter Server Name, authentication, user name & password
- Database Name: `<default>`

*Note: Firewall still needs to be configured in the portal.*