# While MS Visual Studio 2015 using the Explorer window Cloud SQL Database is one I would have chosen to open SQL Server Object Explorer function

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, ssms

While MS Visual Studio 2015 using the Explorer window Cloud SQL Database is one I would have chosen to open SQL Server Object Explorer function.

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:
"Could Explorer has encounter an unexpected error:
The requested action could not be completed.
Details: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: User ID "

On several occasions disconnect and connect Database and Azure account logout / login process perform. After trying in vain, to remain above error message.

I could not find anywhere fix it is to operate.
This can not be able to use and quite annoying.

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Cloud Explorer has encountered an unexpected error:

    The requested action could not be completed.
    Details: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: User ID

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592694/cloud-explorer-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-user-id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud explorer value cannot be null, parameter name: user id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592694/cloud-explorer-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-user-id)